# Rails 3.1: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am running a Rails 3.1. When I connect to my page (hosted via webrick), I am unable to connect from other computers. However, if I connect using localhost:3000, it works. This used to work on Rails 3.0 -- using the same router -- but now it doesn't. Does anyone know what could be wrong? Here is the error:

```
Started GET "/" for 192.168.1.102 at 2011-11-16 21:26:06 -0500
  Processing by MainController#index as HTML
Rendered main/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 12ms (Views: 11.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
[2011-11-16 21:26:06] ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer
    /Users/derek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:56:in `eof?'
    /Users/derek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:56:in `run'
    /Users/derek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Possibly a firewall issue? Make sure the port is set to open

Comment: The router had no firewall enabled. All of the security features I could find were disabled. Let it be known that in Rails 3.0 it worked OK on the same router. It was frustrating.

Comment: Hi, did you get any solution for this? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error will be generated anytime when the server doesn't want to
talk to you, eg. because of auth failure or service outage.

I got the same error.. when I am trying to upload 40+ MB Video file.

Let me know if you get solution of this...

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was because the port 3000 was being blocked by the network where the server was part of. Once that block was removed, it works fine.